# create binary table using wix code and C#

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer

I need query to create binary table using wix code and C#.

eg: i am able to create 'AppSearch' table if not present in the msi using the code below

```
Database database = new Database(tempmsiPath, DatabaseOpenMode.Direct);
string  query = "CREATE TABLE `AppSearch` (`Property` CHAR(255) NOT NULL, `Signature_`   
                 CHAR(255) NOT NULL  PRIMARY KEY `Property`)";
database.Execute(query);
```

but when i try

```
query = "CREATE TABLE `Binary` (`Name` CHAR(255) NOT NULL, `Data` Binary NOT NULL     
          PRIMARY KEY `Name`)";
database.Execute(query);
```

i get the error "**BadQuerySyntaxException was caught**"

**SQL query syntax invalid or unsupported. Database: \c:\xx.msi. Invalid type specifier 'Binary' in SQL query CREATE TABLE `Binary` (`Name` CHAR(255) NOT NULL, `Data` Binary NOT NULL  PRIMARY KEY `Name`).**

The reason i need this is I need to add entries to binary table but some times msi does not have binary table in such cases i need to create the table otherwise i get error unknown table binary.

Is there any any other way to create predefined table 'Binary' using c# code and WIX or let me know what i was missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was under the impression you used WiX to build your MSI and was missing the Binary table.  If you didn't build the MSI and are trying to add the Binary table  ( you would normally do this to create a transform not in the MSI itself )  then the easiest way would probably be:

One Time:
Using ORCA:
1) Create an MSI
2) Add the Binary table to the MSI. ( Right Click, Add Table )
3) Export the new table to an IDT file ( Right Click, Export Tables)

The result will be a file called Binary.idt.  It'll look something like this:  ( whitespaces are important as it's a tab delimited file so create it yourself; don't copy and paste )

```
Name    Data
s72 v0
Binary  Name
```

Now in DTF you can use the Import method on the Database object to import the IDT into the database as the Binary table.

```
database.ImportTable("Binary.idt");
```

Comment: Thanks @Christopher You solution works for me. I was modifying a copy of MSI & using CreateTransformSummaryInfo(,,,) to create MST. Thanks for follow up!

Comment: BTW, in the interest of completeness, the reason your SQL statement failed is because the correct keyword for Binary is OBJECT.  But why mess with SQL when you can just import a table spec... :)

Answer (score 3):

If you use the [EnsureTable Element](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_ensuretable.htm), WiX will build an MSI with these tables even if they don't have any data.  Then you won't need any of this code.

Comment: Thanks for your post. How can i use the same using C# as I do not use XML. I do not find the 'EnsureTable' method in the 'Database' object using C#.

Answer (score 0):

refer by https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/sql-syntax

SQL shoud be

```
CREATE TABLE `Binary` (`Name` CHAR(72) NOT NULL, `Data` OBJECT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY `Name`)
```